# Including header files pulled as a git submodule in a C++ file

Tags: c++, git, git-submodules

I've got some C++ code that depends on a submodule pulled from Git. The files are being developed as an Arduino library, and the submodule dependency is also an Arduino library. Both are compiled through the stable version of the Arduino IDE (1.8.16). The submodule's header file is nested within a few folders. Looking at how C++'s `#include` works, it seems as if there is no way to include a header file that isn't defined as a part of the include path or within the same folder as my own C++ file. I was previously putting the submodule's code in the IDE-defined include path to test other parts of the code, but this will not work when the repository is pulled to another computer. I don't believe I can change the path of the submodule in Git, and I do not believe it a good idea to put my own files in the submodule's folder. Is there some way to handle this within a Git repository such that the file inclusion will work on any other computer that pulls the repo without the need for any extra setup?

Here's how all of the mentioned files are currently set up (these are not the actual file names):

```
ProjectFolder
+-- MyFile.cpp
+-- MyFile.h
+-- AFolder
|   +-- AnotherFolder
|   |   +-- SubModule.cpp
|   |   +-- SubModule.h
```

Comment: This depends on your build system, so to be able to answer this question it needs to be specified which build system you are using -- and once you decide that you'll probably be able to find the answer on stackoverflow already.

Comment: Most C++ compilers have some sort of `-I` (I for Include) flag or similar to tell them *look over here for headers*. How you'll *specify* this / these flags is, as @MicroVirus says, build-system-dependent.